# Populating Google form embedded on my website,through the data at my php.

Tags: php, database, google-api, google-forms, autofill

I embedded a google form in my website.
for example see [www.ayushritolia.com/pinpoint](http://www.ayushritolia.com/pinpoint) , I want to autofill the google form the moment the user enters his/her user Id and clicks on continue. User Id details are already there in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Google Support documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000):

> New Google Forms (No "File" menu at top)
>
> 1. Open the form.
> 2. In the top right, click More [image: three dot menu].
> 3. Choose Get pre-filled link.
> 4. Fill in any answer fields you want to pre-populate.
> 5. Click Submit.
> 6. To send the pre-populated form to respondents, use the link at the top.

Once you follow those instructions you will have a link with the format you can modify to dynamically enter any values you want.

Comment: Thanks Abraham.
Is it that the populated values for all the user will be same in this case?

Comment: Whatever the values in the URL are that's what the users will have prepopulated. So if you give all users the same URL yes. Or you good change the URL for each user and they would get different info.